# How to select a bunch of meshes at once

Tags: mesh, edit-mode, selection-tools

I have one mesh character, I just want to remove the hair, so I go to edit mode, move the cursor into the hair and press <kbd>L</kbd>, but it only selects part of the hair not the full hair, My question is, is there a way, so I can select the hair with one press, so I don't have to press <kbd>L</kbd> and hover on every part of it ? Thanks in advance

[image: demo picture]

Comment: Try selecting the whole body or head with L and then use Ctrl-I to invert the selection. You may have to deselect various other parts such as the eyes before deleting though.

Comment: thats actually work thank you for that

Comment: You're welcome! It depends how the object was created in the first place as to how successful that method will be though.

Answer (score 3):

The shortcut <kbd>L</kbd> calls the operator [Select Linked](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/selecting/linked.html#linked), it additively selects the mesh under the cursor and all its linked elements. If all your hair isn't selected at once, it's because your hair isn't made out of one mesh.
You can simply move your cursor over an unselected hair mesh and hit <kbd>L</kbd> again, and keep going until you are done.

Alternatively, sometimes you have a Vertex Group or a material slot dedicated only to your hair. When it is the case, you can select that material slot or vertex group, and hit the `Select` button in Edit Mode:

[image]

If you find yourself having to often select a specific set of mesh parts that don't have a fast way to be selected, it would be smart to make a vertex group for that purpose.